# How to restrict find command search to return only files modified before certain date?

Tags: linux, find

I'd like to constrain the following search to only files with a modified date <= "2009-05-29 11:59:00"

```
find /path -name "*.sb" ! -name "*[^0-9]*.sb"  -type f -print
```

I'm using CentOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `find /path -mtime +7` will give you files older than 7 days, and `find ! -newer somefile` will give you files older than somefile.  So...

```
touch -d "2009-05-29 11:59:00" timestampfile

find /path -name "*.sb" ! -name "*[^0-9]*.sb" ! -newer timestampfile -type f -print
```

Comment: or simply `-mtime -1` ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would anyone mark down this answer as not helpful?

Comment: The '-newermt "DATE"' is a simpler/more elegeant way if you have GNU findutils installed.  This is a little more portable across various UNIX versions, though it depends on the capabilities of your touch command.

Comment: To be clear:  find /foo/bar/ -type f -newermt "$(date='7 days ago')"

Answer (score 2):

! -newermt '5/29/2009 23:59:00' should work on BSD; there will be a similar option on GNU.

Comment: Its the same switch in GNU.

Comment: yep! this one is great! work on GNU/Linux as such: find . -type f -newermt '9/13/2012 18:09:00'

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path \
  -type f \
  ! -newermt "20090529 1159:00" \
  -regex "./[^0-9]*.sb$" \
  -print
```

You can place the `regex` at the end to speed up the command (place the fastest actions at the start, slowest at the end).

Answer (score -1):

You want -mdate

find /path -name "*.sb" ! -name "*[^0-9]*.sb"  -type f -print -mdate -2009-05-30

Here are a couple of examples:

http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/selecting_files_by_age.shtml
http://www.schuerig.de/michael/linux/snippets.html